# Webservers in VPC, how to make publicly accessible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I recently encountered this question while preparing for AWS certfication. Can someone clarify this please?

What are the steps to place web servers in VPC and making it publicly accessible?

1. routing table, NAT, elastic IP, web server security group
2. IAM user,placement group,ELB
3. NAT, Bucket policy, web server security group

Comment: I guess the answer is option 1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking What's the answer of...

Comment: agree to @MostafizRahman and voting too

Comment: Answer: Option1

Comment: That is a very badly worded question. None of the answers are correct (or the question itself is incorrect). AWS Certification questions would be written much better than that.